# How to apply sum on a list of columns

Tags: list, scala, dataframe, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a list `var aggList : List[String]= List()` the list contains the column names on which aggregation has to be applied.

I generate the dataframe as below:

```scala
var df = sc.parallelize(Seq[(Int, Int, String, Int, Int, Int)](
(1234, 1234, "PRM", 2, 1, 1), 
(1235, 1234, "PRM", 1239, 2, 10), 
(1246, 1234, "PRM", 1234, 5, 15), 
(1247, 1234, "PRM", 1254, 20, 12), 
(1246, 1234, "PRM", 1234, 5, 13), 
(1246, 1234, "SEC", 1234, 7, 15), 
(1249, 1234, "SEC", 1234, 20, 1), 
(1248, 1234, "SEC", 1234, 2, 2))
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6")
```

I need to do `df.groupby(col1).agg(sum(aggList))`

How do I achieve this?